# In ~/.ssh/config make a host that just ... errors

Tags: macos, terminal, catalina, ssh

I would like to start using multiple github accounts. I think the best way is to have a different ssh key per account (correct me if that's a wrong assumption).

I will have `user1.git` and `user2.git` custom hosts defined in `~/.ssh/config` to use in ssh remote urls for git.

And I would like to make it so that copy/pasting the default `git@github.com` URLs and trying to use that doesn't do anything and errors instead, to remind me to specify which account and which user I would like to be using.

So, how can I make such an erroring ssh host?

Ideally I will rename github.com host to something else, default.git or something, so that I can still ssh-access it if it's ever necessary.

Comment: Would editing your config file using different users work?

Comment: @DanRan what do you mean?

Comment: Using the command:sudo nano ~/.ssh/config and then editing the config file in the ~/.ssh directory to have different users. One user for each account.                                                                                
    Host gh
    User git
    Hostname github.com
    Port 22
    etc. etc. etc.

Comment: You are correct, i don't fully understand your question. But Are you not trying to essentially use two different github accounts through ssh?

Comment: @DanRan I see what you mean. One ssh user for `user1`, one ssh user for `user2`. I think I have seen somewhere "always use the git user" when connecting to github.com. And it still doesn't stop me from forgetting to specify the user on remote addition.

Comment: @DanRan yes I am trying to use two different github accounts through ssh. I thought it would be best practice to have two different keys for this.

Comment: Basically you have to follow this approach: [How to manage multiple GitHub accounts on a single machine with SSH keys](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/manage-multiple-github-accounts-the-ssh-way-2dadc30ccaca/). Then you have to set an alias sshgit in your *profile to a shell script which unloads all keys first and then lets you choose to load one of your user keys (user1_key|user2_key) and connects you with the respective account with the right key...

Comment: I'm not sure how github treats using the same key for two different accounts. If github has no problem with it, I would say it more than not doesn't matter if you recycle a key.

Comment: In terms of best practices, by using two keys, yes, you are insulating each account incase one key gets hacked or stolen. However, at the same time, by using two keys, you also have an extra key floating around making things more complicated then they have to be for yourself. The likelihood of your keys getting hacked is low unless you are in and out of coffee shops and using intermittent internet connections or vpn's.

Comment: So for the sake of simplicity, I would try to stick with one key if possible. Now, in terms of github, I am still kind of a newb myself, and don't really know their policy. i also believe github doesn't allow interactive ssh logins. I would have to do some more research in order to give you a proper answer. But I would recommend looking at your ~/.ssh/config file and just entering two different users for each github configuration. Sorry I can't be of more help on this.